# No Provider for Service after including it in module providers array

Tags: angular

I've created a simple wrapper around the HTTP service in Angular and called it `CustomHTTPService`. I am now getting the following error when using my app:

> ERROR Error: No provider for CustomHTTPService!

I've included the provider inside of the module I am using for this set of components but the issue persists.

```
import { CustomHTTPService } from '@libs/custom-http-service';
.
.
.
providers: [
        CustomHTTPService ,
        ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is this app.module.ts? post your whole code

Comment: Remember to `imports: [ HttpClientModule, ... ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add **HttpClientModule** to the imports array. It's a little unfortunate that sometimes these errors aren't very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that somewhere deep in my application, I was importing the same library using an older style that we used previously:

```
import { CustomHTTPService } from 'ui.services/custom-http-service';
```

Instead of:

```
import { CustomHTTPService } from '@libs/custom-http-service';
```

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the **`HttpClientModule`** in your app.module.ts because **`CustomHTTPService`**  internally uses **`HttpClientModule`**

```
imports: [ HttpClientModule ]
```